# How to create a custom hand draw pixel bitmap font?

Tags: bitmap, libgdx

I need to create pixel art font, but I dont know how do I match to current libgdx Bitmap class.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled across https://www.pentacom.jp/pentacom/bitfontmaker2/  I redrew every one of my letters into the website then clicked the "Build font" button in the lower left and it spit out a *.ttf font. Tested the font in Unity3D and it worked great.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Adobe Air app called [Shoebox](http://renderhjs.net/shoebox/) to make manually drawn fonts. You basically draw all the characters into an image, from left to right with a bit of space between them. In Shoebox you type out those same characters and adjust some settings like kerning and line spacing. Then it can export a bitmap font that you can load in LibGDX.  The font consists of a .fnt file and one or more.png files. Put them all in your assets directory and load the font using the .fnt file's name in the BitmapFont constructor.